# Group and calculate three rows in R

Tags: r

Is there a possibility for R to group and calculate 3 rows at a time? Or "simple" to define that the first 3 rows should be combined and then the next 3 and then again the next? For example (like in the picture below) you want to combine the first 3 lines to one line. SDO_ID and time stamp (comparable to time) using the median and Therm using the mean

On the left I have executed a str() function, so that you can see roughly what amount and data formats it is about

[image: Table and data from R]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an increasing number `group` to your data with `rep()` and then use `library(data.table)` to calculate the mean and median for your data and group it by the `group` column.

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
DT <- data.table(temp = rnorm(30), sdo_id = rlnorm(30), z = runif(30) )

DT$group <- rep(1:(nrow(DT)/3), each=3)

DT[, .(mean_temp = mean(temp), median_id = median(sdo_id)), by=group]
```

*EDIT*

If you don't want to add a column, you can use it like this:

```
DT[, .(mean_temp = mean(temp), median_id = median(sdo_id)), by=rep(1:(nrow(DT)/3), each=3)]
```

Comment: Can this be done without adding a new column to the data table? In other words, can `by=` refer to a separate vector object? Adding columns to data frames is prone to introducing bugs when the data frame has a column with that existing name, which can happen when you are trying to write general purpose code.

Comment: Yes, like this: `DT[, .(mean_temp = mean(temp), median_id = median(sdo_id)), by=rep(1:(nrow(DT)/3), each=3)]`

Comment: That fails if you have a column in the data frame `DT` which is called `DT`. The safest way I can think of is to define a function outside the data table expression, `grp=function(){rep(1:(nrow(DT)/3), each=3)}` and then `by=grp()` since then R searches for a function called `grp` and never a column or other vector.

Comment: Thank you!

This code snippet has really helped me a lot

{DT$group <- rep(1:(nrow(DT)/3), each=3}


The rest I did with dplyer (group and then calculate the mean values)

Comment: @DiRoxas you can share your code so others can use it too and you can also upvote the answer if it helped you

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can do using `split`, `aggregate`, `by` and probably more.

[image]

Comment: Interesting (pedagogical) approach to post an image as an answer when the OP posts data as an image in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem with the following code:

```
joinxx$Gruppe <- rep(1:(nrow(joinxx)/3), each=3)
    joinxx %>%
    group_by(Gruppe) %>%
    summarise(SDO_ID = median(SDO_ID), Time = median(Zeitstempel), Wert = mean(Wert)) -> sumjoinxx
```

I wrote this in here once, because I can emphasize the encoding better here.